# /sbin/cryptsetup not found on boot

Tags: linux, boot, lvm, dm-crypt

I've created an encrypted root partition using LUKS which contains a few LVM partitions. I can't boot and get the following output on startup:

```
Begin mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... /scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line 1: /sbin/cryptsetup: not found
```

It still prompts me for the password:

```
Unlocking the disk /dev/sda5 (macbookcrypt)
Enter passphrase: *******************************
cryptsetup: cryptesetup failed, bad password or options?
/scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line 1: /sbin/cryptsetup: not found
```

Yet it fails every time.

My boot command-line is:

```
vmlinuz-3.13.0-37 generic ro root=/dev/mapper/macbooklvm-root cryptopts=target=macbookcrypt,source=/dev/sda5,lvm=macbooklvm recovery initrd=\initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
```

I've added "`dm_crypt`" to `/etc/modules` and then did `update-initramfs` to regenerate with `dm_crypt` included. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 by the way.

In the initramfs shell, I can't seem to locate `cryptsetup` anywhere:

```
(initramfs) cat /proc/modules | grep crypt
dm_crypt 23177 0 - Live 0xffffffffa0006000
(initramfs) find / -iname "cryptsetup"
(initramfs)
```

It appears that the `dm_crypt` module is loaded', so that's good, but cryptsetup isn't present here. How do I install it to my Linux boot? Does it need to be included in `initrd`, `vmlinuz`, or `System` files somehow? I'm new to this hackery.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22 try with `sudo apt install cryptsetup-initramfs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently, I didn't create a `/etc/crypttab` file. Create one, then `update-initramfs -u` to fix the issue.

Comment: Wow thanks for posting your solution, I didn't know it was that simple and for duplicating usbs with encrypted partitions I was doing it the hard way: extracting initrd manually, editing etc/conf/conf.d/cryptroot, changing the uuid for the right one and recreating againt init with gzip and cpio.

Comment: Read the source, Luke. After isolating the script that either copies cryptsetup (or doesn't), I saw that it checks for the presence of `/etc/crypttab` as part of its logic. From there, all downhill ☺

Comment: Now I know why I did it the hard way. If you create an encrypted swap partition and want it to have password so that you can resume from hybernation, update-initramfs doesn't update the swap partition even if it is defined in `/etc/crypttab` so you have to extract init, create an entry in `etc/conf.d/cryptroot` with the swap partition and recreate the init. (At least that is my experience in Debian)

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I was missing the **xts** kernel module from

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Other modules that you might miss could be:

```
raid1
raid456
aes-x86_64
sha512-ssse3
xts
dm-mod
dm-crypt
```

I found the root cause out by adding to the grub command line (linux) this option:

```
break=mount
```

that forces drop to busybox. After that I was able to copy by USB stick ( from another machine) these files on the ramfs:

```
mkdir /boot
mount /dev/sdc1 /boot
cp cryptsetup /sbin/cryptsetup
cp libcryptsetup.so.4.0.0 /lib/libcryptsetup.so.4
cp libpopt.so.0.0.0 /lib/libpopt.so.0
cp libgcrypt.so.11.7.0 /lib/libgcrypt.so.11
cp libgpg-error.so.0.8.0 /lib/libgpg-error.so.0
/boot/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md10 root
```

(I have also root on software raid, no LVM) that gave the error of missing module.

A good idea that came in my mind afterwards would be to copy the above cryptsetup files on the /boot partition in advance, so that you don't have to mess around with an USB stick. Another way is to decompress the initramfs image once (in advance) in e.g. /boot/tmp:

```
gzip -d < ../initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic | cpio --extract --verbose --make-directories --no-absolute-filenames
```

so you have all the workings libs and cryptsetup available, even if your `update-initramfs -k all -c`
has failed after some kernel update.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem that gave me the above error message, but after investigation (as specified above) I got this more specific error message:

```
 cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md10 cryptroot

 device-mapper: table: 252:0: crypt: unknown target type
 ioctl: error adding target to table
```

Solution: Check that /etc/crypttab root device name (cryptroot) matches /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm settings. I had "cryptroot" in other and "root" in other, after syncing the target device names, boot worked like a dream!

After fixing the settings run

```
update-initramfs -c -k all
```